# NameError: name 'self' is not defined, even though it is?

Tags: python, class, oop

Can anyone helps me understand why this is this giving me an error? The error being "NameError: name 'self' is not defined".  I have a similar class higher up in my code and that works fine?

I'm using 'xlrd' and team is a reference to a workbook.sheet_by_name.

```
class Rollout:                                  
    def __init__(self, team, name):
        self.team = team
        self.name = name
        self.jobs = {}
        self.start_row = 1
        self.last_row = self.team.nrows

    for i in range(self.start_row,self.last_row):
            try:
                self.jobs[i-1] =   [str(self.team.cell_value(i,0)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,1)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,2)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,3)).upper(), \
                                    str(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(self.team.cell_value(i,4),0)[3]), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,5)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,6)).upper()]
            except ValueError:
                print "It look's like one of your 'time' cells is incorrect!"
                self.jobs[i-1] =   [str(self.team.cell_value(i,0)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,1)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,2)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,3)).upper(), \
                                    "missing", \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,5)).upper(), \
                                    str(self.team.cell_value(i,6)).upper()]
```

Comment: Is that indentation correct?

Comment: The for loop is not indented correctly

Comment: if `self` is not defined, then you are not inside the method..

Comment: is the indentation correct? can you paste the traceback too?

Comment: Aside: there's no need for to use \ for line continuation inside parentheses `()` or brackets `[]`.

Comment: Yep, it was the indentation... thanks all!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `for` loop is indented incorrectly resulting in it being outside that method's scope but inside the class' scope. This in turn means that `self` is not defined.

Python does interpret that loop code in the scope of the class, but without an instance of the object. Sample malformed code:

```
class Simple(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    print("Here we go!")
    for i in xrange(self.a):
        print(i)
```

Traceback

```
$ python simple.py
Here we go!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Simple(object):
  File "simple.py", line 9, in Simple
    for i in xrange(self.a):
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Python interprets the loop code in the execution scope of the `class` body.  Whatever ends up in the namespace after executing the code in the class scope becomes the attribute dictionary of the class object.  Were there not a `NameError` because of `self`, `Simple.i` would end up being whatever `i` ended up set to after the loop completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you **omit** the "self" keyword in your Constructor's ( **init**) argument, then you will get:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

whenever you use "self" in the constructor method body.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer already tells this, here is just the fixed code of the question, with the `for` loop indented in the `__init__` function:

```py
class Rollout:                                  
    def __init__(self, team, name):
        self.team = team
        self.name = name
        self.jobs = {}
        self.start_row = 1
        self.last_row = self.team.nrows

        for i in range(self.start_row,self.last_row):
                try:
                    self.jobs[i-1] =   [str(self.team.cell_value(i,0)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,1)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,2)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,3)).upper(), \
                                        str(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(self.team.cell_value(i,4),0)[3]), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,5)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,6)).upper()]
                except ValueError:
                    print "It look's like one of your 'time' cells is incorrect!"
                    self.jobs[i-1] =   [str(self.team.cell_value(i,0)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,1)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,2)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,3)).upper(), \
                                        "missing", \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,5)).upper(), \
                                        str(self.team.cell_value(i,6)).upper()]
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while executing my code,

```
#An example of a class
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    description = "This shape has not been described yet"
    author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author = text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
    self.y = self.y * scale
```

Then i kept space before last line of the codes like

```
#An example of a class
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    description = "This shape has not been described yet"
    author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author = text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

Then got no error, So space is the problem..

Comment: Man, it is another problem, and a difference between difficulty of yours one and presented one is like between the sky and the Earth

Comment: It is a different problem here, this one is not about indenting in the `__init__` function but just about the right indentation inside methods of the class. Still helpful for some perhaps who search just for the error, not for the question.

Answer (score -3):

## An example of a class

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    description = "This shape has not been described yet"
    author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author = text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. You're explaining him what a class is which is not what has been asked. Please remove/ edit your answer accordingly